# Add a column and populate based on other columns values

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE trajectory(
    user_id int, 
    session_id int, 
    timestamp timestamp with time zone,
    lat double precision, 
    lon double precision
);

INSERT INTO trajectory(user_id, session_id, timestamp, lat, lon) VALUES 
(1, 25304,'2008-10-23 02:53:04+01', 39.984702, 116.318417),
(1, 25304, '2008-10-23 02:53:10+01', 39.984683, 116.31845), 
(1, 25304, '2008-10-23 02:53:15+01', 39.984686, 116.318417),
(1, 25304, '2008-10-23 02:53:20+01', 39.984688, 116.318385), 
(1, 20959,'2008-10-24 02:09:59+01', 40.008304, 116.319876),
(1, 20959,'2008-10-24 02:10:04+01', 40.008413, 116.319962), 
(1, 20959,'2008-10-24 02:10:14+01', 40.007171, 116.319458),
(2, 55305, '2008-10-23 05:53:05+01', 39.984094, 116.319236), 
(2, 55305, '2008-10-23 05:53:11+01', 39.984198, 116.319322), 
(2, 55305, '2008-10-23 05:53:21+01', 39.984224, 116.319402), 
(2, 34104, '2008-10-23 23:41:04+01', 40.013867, 116.306473),
(2, 34104, '2008-10-23 23:41:16+01', 40.013907, 116.306488);
```

**Question:**

I want to add a column `trip_id` to this table, based on the `user_id` and `session_id` columns, so that when the user's session id changes, I know the user is on a new trip so I add that id to the new `trip` column.

Required output:

```
user_id |session_id  |timestamp              |    lat       |   lon     | trip_id
--------|------------|-----------------------|--------------|-----------|-----------
  1     |     25304  |2008-10-23 02:53:04+01 | 39.984702    |116.318417 |       1
  1     |     25304  |2008-10-23 02:53:10+01 | 39.984683    |116.31845  |       1
  1     |     25304  |2008-10-23 02:53:15+01 | 39.984686    |116.318417 |       1
  1     |     25304  |2008-10-23 02:53:20+01 | 39.984688    |116.318385 |       1
  1     |     20959  |2008-10-24 02:09:59+01 |40.008304     |116.319876 |       2
  1     |     20959  |2008-10-24 02:10:04+01 |40.008413     |116.319962 |       2
  1     |     20959  |2008-10-24 02:10:14+01 |40.007171     |116.319458 |       2
  2     |     55305  |2008-10-23 05:53:05+01 |39.984094     |116.319236 |       1
  2     |     55305  |2008-10-23 05:53:11+01 |39.984198     |116.319322 |       1
  2     |     55305  |2008-10-23 05:53:21+01 |39.984224     |116.319402 |       1
  2     |     34104  |2008-10-23 23:41:04+01 |40.013867     |116.306473 |       2
  2     |     34104  |2008-10-23 23:41:16+01 |40.013907     |116.306488 |       2

How can I do this?
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for these great answers, but all the answers received are kind of retrieving table values, they do not modify the table. Plus, I added the `timestamp` column that I initially omitted thinking that would simplify my question.

Comment: Your table needs a timestamp or sequence column too.

Comment: I opted the `timestamp` column to simplify the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using the window function `lag()` to retrieve the previous row and determine whether or not it has changed, followed by the window function `sum()` to retrieve the `trip_id`:

```
with cte as (
  select *, case when 
                 session_id - lag(session_id, 1, session_id) 
                              over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) = 0 
                 then 0 else 1 end as diff
  from trajectory
)
select user_id, session_id, timestamp,  lat, lon, 1 + sum(diff) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) as trip_id
from cte
order by user_id, timestamp
```

Assuming the user_id/timestamp is unique, the update can be :

```
ALTER TABLE trajectory ADD COLUMN trip_id int;

with cte as (
  select *, case when session_id - lag(session_id, 1, session_id) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) = 0 then 0 else 1 end as diff
  from trajectory
),
cte2 as (
  select user_id,   session_id, timestamp,  lat, lon, 1 + sum(diff) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) as trip_id
  from cte
  order by user_id, timestamp
)
UPDATE trajectory 
SET trip_id = cte2.trip_id
FROM cte2
WHERE trajectory.timestamp = cte2.timestamp and trajectory.user_id = cte2.user_id
```

Result :

| user_id | session_id | timestamp | lat | lon | trip_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:04+01 | 39.984702 | 116.318417 | 1 |
| 1 | 25304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:10+01 | 39.984683 | 116.31845 | 1 |
| 1 | 25304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:15+01 | 39.984686 | 116.318417 | 1 |
| 1 | 25304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:20+01 | 39.984688 | 116.318385 | 1 |
| 1 | 20959 | 2008-10-24 02:09:59+01 | 40.008304 | 116.319876 | 2 |
| 1 | 20959 | 2008-10-24 02:10:04+01 | 40.008413 | 116.319962 | 2 |
| 1 | 20959 | 2008-10-24 02:10:14+01 | 40.007171 | 116.319458 | 2 |
| 2 | 55305 | 2008-10-23 05:53:05+01 | 39.984094 | 116.319236 | 1 |
| 2 | 55305 | 2008-10-23 05:53:11+01 | 39.984198 | 116.319322 | 1 |
| 2 | 55305 | 2008-10-23 05:53:21+01 | 39.984224 | 116.319402 | 1 |
| 2 | 34104 | 2008-10-23 23:41:04+01 | 40.013867 | 116.306473 | 2 |
| 2 | 34104 | 2008-10-23 23:41:16+01 | 40.013907 | 116.306488 | 2 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/efq5QKXQ)

Comment: I editted my question to give more details.

Comment: I have edited my answer and included the statement needed

Answer (score 2):

We can approach this with a gaps-and-island technique. Assuming that you have a column to order your dataset, say `ordering_id`:

```
select t.*, 
    count(*) 
        filter(where session_id is distinct from lag_session_id) 
        over(partition by user_id order by ordering_id) trip_id
from (
    select t.*, 
        lag(session_id) over(partition by user_id order by ordering_id) lag_session_id
    from trajectory t
) t
```

The idea is to bring the "preceding" session id of the same user with `lag`, then to compare it with the value on the current row; we can then count how many times it changed, which defines the trip id.

| user_id | session_id | lat | lon | ordering_id | lag_session_id | trip_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25304 | 39.984702 | 116.318417 | 1 | *null* | 1 |
| 1 | 25304 | 39.984683 | 116.31845 | 2 | 25304 | 1 |
| 1 | 25304 | 39.984686 | 116.318417 | 3 | 25304 | 1 |
| 1 | 25304 | 39.984688 | 116.318385 | 4 | 25304 | 1 |
| 1 | 20959 | 40.008304 | 116.319876 | 5 | 25304 | 2 |
| 1 | 20959 | 40.008413 | 116.319962 | 6 | 20959 | 2 |
| 1 | 20959 | 40.007171 | 116.319458 | 7 | 20959 | 2 |
| 2 | 55305 | 39.984094 | 116.319236 | 8 | *null* | 1 |
| 2 | 55305 | 39.984198 | 116.319322 | 9 | 55305 | 1 |
| 2 | 55305 | 39.984224 | 116.319402 | 10 | 55305 | 1 |
| 2 | 34104 | 40.013867 | 116.306473 | 11 | 55305 | 2 |
| 2 | 34104 | 40.013907 | 116.306488 | 12 | 34104 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/40y2aIAh)

Comment: By "column to order" you mean something like timestamp? Or the session_id would do that just fine?

Comment: I have the `timestamp` (e.g. value: `2008-10-23 23:41:04+01` ) I omitted that in my example to simplify the question. Can that column serve as the "ordering column"?

Comment: @AminaUmar: yes a timestamp column would do, as long as there are no duplicate rows for a given user_id/timestamp tuple.

Comment: Just 1 more question regarding this answer. How do I modify the table adding the `trip_id` column. As it is, it retrieving result not modifying the table.

Comment: question edited to include `timestamp` + required modified table.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach would involve:

- selecting the minimum record of your identifier
- applying a `DENSE RANK` by ordering on it.

If you don't have any ordering field, you can use "*ctid*" for that purpose: it's a field that stores the physical location of each row within the table. Otherwise use the timestamp field in place of "*ctid*".

```
ALTER TABLE trajectory ADD COLUMN trip_id INT;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ctid, 
           user_id, 
           MIN(ctid) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, session_id) AS parts 
    FROM trajectory
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT ctid,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY parts) AS trip_id 
    FROM cte
)
UPDATE trajectory 
SET trip_id = cte2.trip_id
FROM cte2
WHERE trajectory.ctid = cte2.ctid;
```

**Output**:

| user_id | session_id | lat | lon | trip_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25304 | 39.984702 | 116.318417 | 1 |
| 1 | 25304 | 39.984683 | 116.31845 | 1 |
| 1 | 25304 | 39.984686 | 116.318417 | 1 |
| 1 | 25304 | 39.984688 | 116.318385 | 1 |
| 1 | 20959 | 40.008304 | 116.319876 | 2 |
| 1 | 20959 | 40.008413 | 116.319962 | 2 |
| 1 | 20959 | 40.007171 | 116.319458 | 2 |
| 2 | 55305 | 39.984094 | 116.319236 | 1 |
| 2 | 55305 | 39.984198 | 116.319322 | 1 |
| 2 | 55305 | 39.984224 | 116.319402 | 1 |
| 2 | 34104 | 40.013867 | 116.306473 | 2 |
| 2 | 34104 | 40.013907 | 116.306488 | 2 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pmMYXkfLqNgcYxSXBjWTi9/0).

Comment: Can't we use dense_rank directly? `dense_rank() over (partition by user_id order by session_id desc)`, I feel that I'm missing something!

Comment: Yeah, the field "*session_id*" doesn't give an order, that's the problem. It's just an identifier. The fact that in the sample data, session_id is ordered doesn't necessarily imply all session ids will be ordered to match the actual order.

Comment: Aha, the OP doesn't mention that, but it makes sense.

Comment: @lemon I edited this question giving additional information on the expected answer.

Comment: Just need to transform the select into an update, being followed by the `ALTER TABLE` that adds the field. Check the updated answer.